# How to enter user input in jmeter console (without doing parameterization)

Tags: groovy, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have to give the user input in the Jmeter console.

For example

Using scanner or other libraries i need to enter input values in the Jmeter console.

Jmeter log

Enter input : (Here i need to give input) testinputuser2

I have tried some code in jsr223 using groovy i got **java i/o execption: The handle is invalid**

Could you please give the best solution for this it would be good

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you without seeing your "some code".

You should be able to use [System.in](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) class which provides you access to [STDIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) without any issues. Something like:

```
def userInput = System.in.withReader { reader ->
    OUT.println 'Please enter test parameter'
    reader.readLine()
}

OUT.println('You have entered: ' + userInput)

vars.put('userInput', userInput)
```

[image]

Be informed that due to multithreaded nature you wil need to provide the input for each thread (virtual user) so the suitable location for the JSR223 Sampler would be [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) with 1 user and iteration.

Comment: I used this same code i am receiving java.io.IOException Stream closed  error could you please help me on this issue